# jquery cant get value of text box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

i am building one form with fancy box, form work fine but i could not get value from text box.

my java script is

```
$(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var yourName = $("input#yourName").val();
        alert(yourName);
        if (yourName == "") {
            $('input#yourName').css({
                backgroundColor: "#F90"
            });
            $("input#yourName").focus();
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bin/form1.php",
            data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
            context: document.body,
            success: function (res) {
                var success = '<?php echo sprintf(_m('Success name % s '), "" ); ?>';
                success = success.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
                var RegularExpression = new RegExp(success);

                if (RegularExpression.test(res)) {
                    alert('Message Sent');
                    $.fancybox.close();
                } else {
                    alert('Error While processing');
                }
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

now my html is

```
<div style="display:none; height:450px">
    <form id="login_form" action="">
        <p id="login_error">
            Please, enter data
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_friend_post" />
        <label for="yourName" style="margin-right:110px;">
            <?php _e( 'Your name', 'newcorp') ; ?>
        </label>
        <input id="yourName" type="text" name="yourName" value="" class="text_new " />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" class="text_new" style="background:#930; color:#FFF; width:250px; margin-left:170px" />
    </form>
</div>
```

i am opening this fancy box popup from

```
<a id="tip5" title="" href="#login_form"><?php echo "Login" ; ?></a>
```

every thing work fine but i can't get value of `yourName` even alert is showing blank.

Thanks

Comment: do you try your whole code withih DOM ready function?

Comment: Does the css change (`$('input#yourName').css({backgroundColor:"#F90"});`) work?

Comment: Just make sure you are writing this jquery code on the same page where your form is, unless when dom will be ready, it will not be able to find that button.

Comment: dear @Thomas yes css works fine but value is zero

Comment: have you seen http://fancybox.net/blog No.5? why not `bind` the form `submit` event rather than the button `click` event since your button type is `submit`?

Answer (score 2):

instead of this

```
var yourName = $("input#yourName").val();
```

try

```
var yourName = $("input[name='yourName']:text").val();
```

this will make ur function read the value of text box .

Comment: Hi @sneha.kamble , I've just used your suggestion and it works, thank you so much. I was just wondering: do you know why the first way does not work?

Comment: @molli, I am glad that it worked. the first solution din work cause '#' is for id not name. so for id u can use                             var yourName = $("input[id='yourId']:text").val();

Comment: @molli...Or you can simpley write..  $("#yourId").val();                      bt 'yourId' should be of ypur textbox ID not generic ID

Comment: I'm ashamed I haven't seen it :D
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with your form, it should be better to use

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () { ... })
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function () { ... })
```

Secondly, you should encapsulate your code into `$(document).ready(function () { .. });`

Here is a working example ;) http://jsfiddle.net/aANmv/1/

Comment: @air you can bind submit to a specific form

Comment: @air you can bind the submit event like `$(document).on('submit', 'form#login_form', function() {...});` The selector can be more specific than just `form`

Comment: in firebug i see this error "$(document).on is not a function" on $(document).on('submit', 'form#login_form', function(e){

Comment: @air which version of jQuery are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the ID of Your input is not changed by fancybox at the time of opening the popup.
2. Instead of directly catching up the `click` event try to `live` the event if using jQuery 1.7 > or `on` when using jQuery 1.7 <.

`live`:

```js
$("#button").live('click', function() { ... });
```

`on`:

```js
$("#button").on('click', function() { ... });
```

Also try to load the javascript after the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").live('click', function() { ... });
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of that

```
$(function() {
```

try

```
$(document).ready() {
```

this way you are sure that code is executed only after the document has loaded completely. Oh, and you could use `#yourName` instead of `input#yourName`, if i'm not wrong it should be faster.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same, but they are still good advices. Maybe not an answer, but surely not a "wrong" or "false" one, since everyother anwser here says almost the same about using the document.ready function. Don't understand the down votes.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second advice but the first one does absolutely nothing differently, therefore not a good answer. Anyway it doesn't help to solve the existing problem